# Create horizontal box-navigation with MDL

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm trying to create a sort of a horizonal navigation with MDL, where each nav item is like a small box with a tiny title and a large title. I haven't really found some pre-made component so I'm trying to utilize the ul > li structure.

Each item should be the same width and height, with "Section 1, 2 etc." always in the same place - close to the upper left corner, and the length of the larger titles shouldn't affect the size of the box, nor the border-right height which should always be the same(spreading from top to bottom). I'm quite new to this MDL stuff so if anyone could help a bit with this I would be grateful.

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRbrGp

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

.section-nav {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.max-width {
    max-width: 1400px;
}

.section-nav-list-item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    width: 230px;
}

.section-nav-list {
    background-color: white;
}

.section-nav-list-item:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.section-nav-list-item--selected {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `display: flex;` to `.section-nav-list`

```
.section-nav-list {
   display: flex; // Added
   background-color: white;
   padding-left: 0; // Added
}
```

then, remove the width of `li` and set `flex: 1`

```
.section-nav-list-item {
  flex: 1 // Added
  /* width: 230px; */ // Removed
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
```